# Client-side data saving to hard drive

Tags: javascript, html, web

I need to save some table content in my html page frame by clicking a button. After that in "Save as" dialog box I want to select a file name and save it somewhere.. The question is how to do this. I see at least two ways. 1st one is server-side, 2nd is client-side. For some reasons I prefer to use the client-side approach. But how to do this? Which technology to prefer? Of course it needs to support most popular browsers. And somehow I need to show "Save as" dialog to the user to allow him/her to select the file location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you're trying to do, maybe try base64 encoding it into a data URL, then setting that as the value of the link to Save as. You can use the btoa() native function in Javascript to take a string, encode it to base64, and ask the user right-click and save link as.

```
<script LANGUAGE="Javascript">
function initialize(berliner) {
document.getElementById("aharef").href="data:text/plain;base64,"+btoa(berliner);
}
</script>
<a href="javascript:" id="aharef">Just an example link. Right click and save as to save when ready.</a>
<input type="button" value="Get ready." onClick="initialize('I am a jelly donut.');">
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I'll try to play w/ this approach and see how it looks like)

Answer (score 0):

**Short:**

That is not possible on client-side.

**Long:**

Using standard HTML5 technologies you can only *read* files using the `File API`. The only way to really save a file programmatically to the user's hard drive is by using Microsoft's `ActiveX` technology (which is ugly and only works in IE).

**Solution:**

In your case I'd suggest to provide a button, which causes your application to create the document having the necessary formatting and send it as a **download** to the user.

Comment: Thank you for your update! I'll keep in reserve the server-side solution just in case :)

Answer (score 0):

Refining the answer by tomysshadow (which I upvoted):

```
<script LANGUAGE="Javascript">
  function initialize(txt) {
    document.getElementById("theLink").href="data:text/plain;base64,"+btoa(txt);
  }
</script>
<a 
  id="theLink"
  download="myFile.txt" 
  href="javascript:" 
  onclick="initialize('Here is the contents of the file');" 
>Save</a>
```

With this code there is no need to prepare the download before doing it. You also do not need to right click and select Save link as. And you can specify the name of the file in the code. I tried it in Firefox only.

Try it here https://jsfiddle.net/ad3u85ym/